How to change the chart arch color on mouse hover effect?
How to do the pie chart arch color change on mouse hover ?
Using .outerRadius(103 + 5); for hover  transform, but how to apply some color change for arch? Please help
var arcOver = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(103 + 5);



 var toCSV = [
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "0",
    "label": "LYQ1",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "10",
    "label": "LYQ2",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "16",
    "label": "LYQ3",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "10",
    "label": "LYQ4",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "0",
    "label": "CYQ1",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "10",
    "label": "CYQ2",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "16",
    "label": "CYQ3",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
    "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
    "value": "10",
    "label": "CYQ4",
    "children": []
  }
];
 var margin = {top: 30,right: 20,bottom: 20,left: 20 },
                 width = 400,
                 height = 400;
                 var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 4;
                 var donutWidth = 75; 
                 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
                 var count = 0;
                // var svg = d3.select("div#donuts").append("svg")
                 var svg = d3.select("#charts").append("svg")
                             .attr('width', width)
                             .attr('height', height)
                             .append('g')
                             .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
                             ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
                 
                 
                  var arc = d3.arc()
                              .innerRadius(0)
                              .outerRadius(100);
                     //        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
                  var arcOver = d3.arc()
                                  .innerRadius(0)
                                .outerRadius(103 + 5);
                
                             
                            
                             
                   var pie = d3.pie()
                             .sort(null)
                             .value(function (d) {
                             return d.value;
                             });
                   var pcnt =  d3.sum(toCSV, function(d) { 
                                 return d.value; 
                                   });
                         
                         // avoiding overlap labels
                        var getAngle = function (d) {
                                return (180 / Math.PI * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 - 90);
                            };
                        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                                   .data(pie(toCSV))
                                   .enter().append("g")
                                   .attr('class',"arc")
                                   .on("mouseover", function() {
                                        d3.select(this).select("path").transition().attr("d",arcOver).duration(200);
                             //   tooltip.style("display", null);
                                
                                        })
                                   .on("mousemove", function(d) {
                              tooltip.transition().duration(200)
                             .style("opacity", 0.9);
                              tooltip.select("div").html( d.data.name  +" <br><strong>"  + d.data.value + "</strong>")
                             .style("position", "fixed")
                             .style("text-align", "center")
                               .style("width", "120px")
                             .style("height", "45px")
                             .style("padding", "2px")
                             .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
                             .style("background", "lightsteelblue")
                             .style("border", "0px")
                             .style("border-radius", "8px")
                             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");   
                                        })
                                   .on("mouseout", function() {
                                         tooltip.style("display", "none")
                                         d3.select(this).select("path").transition()  
                                   .attr("d",arc)
                                   .duration(500);
                                        })
                                  
                              /*   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                                            d3.select(this)
                                               .transition()
                                               .duration(1000)
                                               .attr("d", arcOver);
                                        })
                        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                            d3.select(this).transition()            
                               .attr("d", arc)
                               .attr("stroke","none");
                        });*/

                         var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                           .attr("class", "tooltip")
                           .style("opacity", 0.5);

                         tooltip.append("rect")
                           .attr("width", 30)
                           .attr("height", 20)
                           .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
                           .style("opacity", 0.5);

                         tooltip.append("div")
                           .attr("x", 15)
                           .attr("dy", "1.2em")
                           .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                           .attr("font-size", "1.5em")
                           .attr("font-weight", "bold");


                
                     g.append("path")
                         .attr("d", arc)
                         .style("fill", function (d) {
                             return color(d.data.name);
                          });
                    
                     count = 0;
                    //Legend for charts 
                     var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                         .data(toCSV).enter()
                         .append("g").attr("class", "legend")
                         .attr("legend-id", function(d) {
                             return count++;
                         })
                         .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                             return "translate(-30," + (-90 + i * 20) + ")";
                         });
                        
                     
                     legend.append("rect")
                         .attr("x", width / 1.9)
                        .attr("word-wrap","break-word")
                         .attr("width", 18).attr("height", 18)
                         .style("fill", function(d) {
                             return color(d.name);
                         });
                     legend.append("text").attr("x", width / 2)
                         .attr("y", 9).attr("dy", ".35em")
                       
                         .style("text-anchor", "end").text(function(d) {
                             return d.label;
                         });
                  
           
 .chart {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 3px;
}

.chart div {
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: red;
}
rect.background {
  fill: white;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

bar {
    fill: #8CD3DD;
  }
  
bar:hover {
    fill: #F56C4E;
  }

/* .tick:nth-child(3n) text {
    visibility: hidden;
} */

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

Style northward tooltips differently
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}


svg text.label {
  fill:#ff0000;
  font: 25px; 
  text-anchor: middle; 
  font-weight: 400;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 125%;
  text-anchor: start;
}


path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
  /*   fill: none; */ /* commenting out to show multiple ring donut chart. */
}

pathline {
  fill: none;
      stroke-width: 2;
  
  stroke: #000;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}



.graph {
    width: auto;
}

.tooltip {
    color:black;
}

.axis {
    font: 12px sans-serif , Georgia, Arial ;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #dadada;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

/* ANGULAR MODAL */

.dialogdemoBasicUsage #popupContainer {
  position: relative; }

.dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px; }

.dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer, .dialogdemoBasicUsage .footer > code {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 50px; }

.dialogdemoBasicUsage button {
  width: 200px; }

.dialogdemoBasicUsage div#status {
  color: #c60008; }

.dialogdemoBasicUsage .dialog-demo-prerendered md-checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  
/* Angular grids */

.gridListdemoBasicUsage md-grid-list {
  margin: 8px; }

gridListdemoBasicUsage .gray {
  background: #f5f5f5; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage .green {
  background: #b9f6ca; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage .yellow {
  background: #ffff8d; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage .blue {
  background: #84ffff; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage .purple {
  background: #b388ff; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage .red {
  background: #ff8a80; }

.gridListdemoBasicUsage md-grid-tile {
  transition: all 400ms ease-out 50ms; }
  
md-grid-list md-grid-tile md-grid-tile-footer, md-grid-list md-grid-tile md-grid-tile-header{
       height: 25px;
   }
  
  .svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 12%;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.svg-content-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
.svg-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#linechart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}



/* TESTING GRIDS */

.chart-tile {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .s64 {
  font-size: 64px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .s32 {
  font-size: 48px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-list {
  margin: 8px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 3px #888888;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 50ms; 
}

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile md-grid-tile-footer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  height: 36px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile-footer figcaption {
  width: 100%; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile-footer figcaption h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; }


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at https://material.angularjs.org/license.
*/

@media (min-width: 1200px){
.container {
    width: 1400px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 260px) and (min-width: 1600px) {
.container {
    width: 1700px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
}

#wrapper{
    border-style:solid;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#dropdown
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:80px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

/* Styles go here */
    .gridster-item {
        background-color: darkgrey;
    }
    .my-class{
      border:1px solid red;
      height:50px;
    }

    body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.container
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;  
}
.left-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.left-text, .right-text
{
  font: 300 16px/1.6 'Helvetica Neue' sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
  .left-div, .right-div
    {
       max-width: 100%;
    }
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="charts"></div>



JSFiddle


Understand how your colors are applied:

The colors you see there come from a predefined palette of colors (d3.schemeCategory20 in this case):
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

This part defines the initial state/look of your slices in the pie chart:
g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.data.name); // <-- fill each slice with a unique color for a unique name
  });


Understand what happens on mouse over:

.on("mouseover", function () {
    d3.select(this)
      .select("path")
      .transition()
      .attr("d", arcOver) // <-- this is applying your radius transformation on hover
      .duration(200);
  })


Combine the two concepts:

.on("mouseover", function () {
    d3.select(this)
      .select("path")
      .transition()
      // increase the radius:
      .attr("d", arcOver)
      // AND ALSO change the colors:
      .style("fill", function (d) {
        // get the current color:
        var fillColor = color(d.data.name);
        // i.e. increase its brightness a little:
        var brigtherColor = d3.color(fillColor).brighter(0.5);
        // apply the brightened color
        return brigtherColor;
      })
      // we can do the same to the stroke/border:
      .style("stroke", function (d) {
        var fillColor = color(d.data.name);
        // in this case we darken it a little to show the contrast:
        var darkerStrokeColor = d3.color(fillColor).darker(0.5);
        return darkerStrokeColor;
      })
      .duration(200);
  })


Remember to reset the transformations on mouse out:

.on("mouseout", function () {
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
    d3.select(this)
      .select("path")
      .transition()
      // reset the hover transformations back to initial state:
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.name);
      })
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .duration(500);
  });

